# How to add custom select in product page?

Tags: shopify

how to add custom select in product page and i want two option value one is default value and second is when i select second number option from select than product price `decrese Rs -50 is fixed in every product` and `show one input box below our select button` when select second option from select than add product in cart and show that input value inserted by user. Can it possible in product page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Good Question....

Please see this link for more info :- https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Get-customization-information-for-products/td-p/616503

I have alredy Implemented in my site and it's works great at prouct page.

Comment: Yes that's fine work for me and understanding. Thank you very much @Magento_Bhurio